# Individually adding Buttons

Tags: java, button

I plan to make a text Adventure for a school project, for this I need to add individual buttons which all have actions

Example:

> You stand before a troll, a button shows "Attack" and it actually lets
>   you attack
>
> you stand before a door, a button on the exact same spot shows "Open"
>   and it opens the door

Every tutorial I've found only shows how to make buttons and add them but I need to individually generate buttons with full functions.

Comment: You have your attack and open button for example, at the same position. You only have to change the visiblity of these buttons.
Like `if(//stand before a troll){  attackButton.setVisible(true); `
`openButton.setVisible(false);}` and so on.

Comment: oh its really that easy..?
thank you!

i thought of a way to only generate them when needed but afterwards...it makes no sense...xD

thank you and sorry^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create all of your buttons and place them where you want to (same position as you mentioned). After that you only have to change the visibility of the buttons with the `setVisible()` method.

Like this:

```
if(/*stand before a troll condition*/)
{
    attackButton.setVisible(true);
    openButton.setVisible(false);
}
else if(/*stand before a door condition*/)
{
    attackButton.setVisible(false);
    openButton.setVisible(true);
}
else  // standing before nothing
{
    attackButton.setVisible(false);
    openButton.setVisible(false);
}
```